# Transfer registered users from one firebase app to another

Tags: firebase

My firebase app has a list of registered users. These were created with Email & Password Authentication.

I want to transfer the firebase data and the list of users to another firebase app.

Transferring the firebase data is straightforward, but how can I transfer the registered users and keep their uid's?

Is this possible and if so, what is the best way to do it?

Comment: Email firebase-support@google.com and they'll get the process kicked off.

Answer (score 53):

You should use the Firebase admin tools.

You may install the admin tools using this command:

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

Export command, that generates the  **AllUsers.json** file:

```
firebase auth:export AllUsers.json --project projectId
```

On the other account use the following command to import the generated file.

```
firebase auth:import AllUsers.json --project projectId
```

Comment: You must use "firebase login" to authenticate each account, prior to export/import. You also have to specify "--project projectId" for each command. Other than that, this answer saved me. Thank You.

Comment: if you are importing and run into this error `HTTP Error: 400, CONFIGURATION_NOT_FOUND` then check you have created/enabled the "Email/Password" provider under "Authentication" in the firebase UI

Answer (score 39):

The answer above doesn't work by it self as all the passwords from the previous project will have different *password hashes*. You need to specify the old hash (exporting project) when you import the new users.

[image]

Click on this menu item and all of the settings you need for doing the firebase auth:import command will show up. Here's what I see:

```
hash_config {
  algorithm: SCRYPT,
  base64_signer_key: <long string of random characters>,
  base64_salt_separator: <short string of random characters>,
  rounds: 8,
  mem_cost: 14,
}
```

I can then do the command successfully

```
firebase auth:import ./users.json --hash-algo=scrypt --rounds=8 --mem-cost=14 --hash-key=<long string of random characters> --salt-separator=<short string of random characters>
```

[How to set hash-key option for auth:import after default auth:export in firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45404874/how-to-set-hash-key-option-for-authimport-after-default-authexport-in-firebase)

Comment: if anyone find this useful, you should use the hash_config of the source app (where you exported the users from) and not from the target project

Answer (score 10):

I am just providing a summary of the two best rated answers (thanks to Genaro Costa and Ben Winding) together with some clarifications that can be found in the comments (thanks to Gary Kipnis). To migrate passwords between Firebase projects one has to:

1. Install the Firebase admin tools with:

`npm install -g firebase-tools`

2. Log into the source project with:

`firebase login`

3. Export the hashed passwords to a **AllUsers.json** file with:

`firebase auth:export AllUsers.json --project <projectId>`

Here you have to replace  with your project ID.

4. Log into the destination project (same CL as in step 2)
5. Import the passwords using the hash password configuration of the source app using:

`firebase auth:import ./AllUsers.json --hash-algo=SCRYPT --rounds=8 --mem-cost=14 --hash-key=<long string of random characters> --salt-separator=<short string of random characters> --project <projectId>`

where the parameters can be found in the Firebase Authentication console ([see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRqvd.png) or Ben Winding's), and have the structure:

```
hash_config {
  algorithm: SCRYPT,
  base64_signer_key: <long string of random characters>,
  base64_salt_separator: <short string of random characters>,
  rounds: 8,
  mem_cost: 14,
}
```

Comment: Really useful summary - one modification I would suggest is to add --project <projectId> to the end of step 5.

Comment: done, thanks David

Answer (score 7):

Just got this from Firebase Support:

> Just recently Firebase, has rolled-out the new API for downloading
>   your Firebase Auth users. To migrate your users to/from other Firebase
>   projects, you may use this new CLI auth:export tool which is available
>   at [Github](https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Ffirebase%2Ffirebase-tools%2Freleases%2Ftag%2Fv3.3.0&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNEQaXFnvdk3lykrVNAlfaQ8GitWIw). For more information you may check on our Firebase docs.
>   Additionally, we made a [guide](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1KMIPV4MLIz9t4sHSkJah562XGt8xWFEUnV77oKfSkkQ/preview) for importing/exporting
>   users on your projects.

Comment: The link for the guide has expired.