# Migrate Cloud Firestore project to another Cloud Firestore project

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I need to change my Project Id because the firebase auth link to verify is showing the project id on the link, and the name of the project has changed due to a rebrand. Based on the info i have found, it seems unlikely possible to change the Project Id. I was thinking of migrating all the data from the old database to the new one with the new Project Id. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 5):

Firebase has a documentation page dedicated to moving Firestore data from one project to another:

[Move data between projects | Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/move-data)

To move your authentication user accounts, you can use this method:

[Transfer registered users from one firebase app to another – StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56036644).

If you're using cloud functions and have environment configurations, you can transfer them by running the following command:

```
firebase functions:config:clone --from OLD_PROJECT_ID --project NEW_PROJECT_ID
```

Then you can deploy your cloud functions to the new project by changing your `project` in your `.firebaserc` to your new project ID and then running:

```
firebase deploy --only functions
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is, you can export the entire database and import it into another project. It is well documented here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import

Comment: Looks quite confusing to understand. Does this able to copy all the data including auth, firebase storage and everything else?

Comment: No, this is just for moving Firestore, did not understand you wanted to move auth and storage as well. I know there is an export / import tool for firebase auth. I have never moved a storage, so not sure about that one.

Comment: Because https://food-plus-life.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/action?mode=verifyEmail&oobCode=qfIVxIkeasgfNlQkLl0SWvRy7UCaVxeSXKrsP3CPNKkAAAFpo3Lm4Q&apiKey=AIzaSyCumeIqTuwCEEtbcB6GWRA7HH1lI2lVtV4&lang=en           because the company faced a rebrand and the email auth verification is showing the project ID which consist of our old company name

Comment: And you are sure it is the Project ID that is shown, not the "Public-facing name"? There is a setting for changing the "Public-facing name" if you go to "settings" and then to "general" in the Firebase console.

Comment: Project name
Green Hero
Project ID 
food-plus-life
Public-facing name 
Green Hero