# Transfer registered users from one firebase app to another without duplicating user email

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-tools

I have two firebase app with list of registered users. These were created with Email & Password Authentication.

I had transfer the the list of authentication user data from my second firebase app to my first firebase app by using firebase CLI.

```
firebase auth:export AllUsers.json --project projectId
firebase auth:import AllUsers.json --project projectId
```

I referred this similar question too
[Transfer registered users from one firebase app to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36032582/transfer-registered-users-from-one-firebase-app-to-another)

But the problem is already there we have same email authenticated users in both firebase app. because of there **User UID** are not same in both app, when export time it creates another new user for the same email.

Is this possible to avoid this kind of scenario when auth users export time and what is the way to do it?

Comment: This sounds like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Are both apps using a different project? Or are they using the same project?

Comment: yes both apps are using two different firebase projects. the thing I need to do is stop the continuation of my second app and migrate those users authentication data into my first app with other relevant user related data nodes. but the problem is if same user have two different account in both apps how can I avoid it display two authentication rows for the same user with  two different User UID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to create a mapping from the UID in the old and the new app (probably based on having a matching email address), and use that to migrate the data from the old project to the new one.

If the user has data in the new project too, you will need to merge the old data with the new. There's unfortunately no way to avoid this.